# Can't read file in kotlin even though the file is in the same path as main.kt

Tags: linux, file, kotlin

I'm currently learning kotlin. Right now I am trying to learn file reading. For that I'm following the tutorial on Baeldung: https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/read-file.
The problem I ran into is that the text file i have created and saved in the same folder as main.kt (../src/main/kotlin) is not being read in. It does not exist according to Intelij.

Here the functions I used

```
fun readFileLineByLineUsingEachLine(filename: String) = File(filename).forEachLine {
    println(it)
}
```

and

```
val inputStream: InputStream = File ("Kotlin2.txt").inputStream()
val inputString = inputStream.reader().use {it.readText()}
println (inputString)
```

I am using Ubuntu which I do not have much experience with. I hope I can find some help here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current directory, where it looks for the file, is not the directory that contains your main.kt. You can see where it's looking by making this small change:

```
val inputStream: InputStream = File("Kotlin2.txt").absoluteFile.inputStream()
```

The `absoluteFile` "property" (which is actually a call to `getAbsoluteFile()`) makes it print an error message containing the full path.

Comment: Thank you. I have moved the file to the (unexpected) expected folder. Now both functions work.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost certainly because the [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) isn't what you think it is!

An *absolute* pathname (e.g. `/home/alice/mydir/myfile.txt`) will always refer to the same file; but a *relative* pathname (e.g. `mydir/myfile.txt` or `Kotlin2.txt`) can refer to different files, depending on the current working directory.

For a Kotlin (or Java) program, the current working directory will depend on how you run the program:

- When run from the command line (e.g. with `kotlin myapp.jar`), it inherits the working directory from the shell running it — which might be your home directory, if you haven't used `cd` to change it.
- When run from an IDE, the IDE will set the working directory. For example, in IntelliJ the run configuration you use will probably have a setting for the working directory; see [these](/questions/7461987/intellij-problem-withget-current-working-directory) [questions](/questions/56212815/intellij-how-to-set-default-working-directory).
- When launched from the desktop, it might use your home directory (depending on the OS).
- When run from within Tomcat, the current directory is usually set from `$CATALINA_BASE` or `$CATALINA_HOME`; see [this question](/questions/18753663/what-determines-the-current-working-directory-of-tomcat-java-process).
- When run from other programs, it'll depend upon the program.

Your program can get its current working directory with e.g. `Path.of("").toAbsolutePath()`; see [this question](/questions/4871051/how-to-get-the-current-working-directory-in-java). (There doesn't seem to be a general way to change it while the program is running, though [this question](/questions/840190/changing-the-current-working-directory-in-java) mentions some workarounds.)

So the solution is either to move your file into the right directory, or access it via an absolute pathname — or at least, one that's relative to the current directory.

Also worth mentioning that configuration files and other resources are generally not located directly from the filesystem, but accessed as [system resources](/questions/42739807/how-to-read-a-text-file-from-resources-in-kotlin), which allows much more flexibility in how apps are installed and run. Frameworks/platforms such as Spring or Android also provide their own ways to access resource files.